# Issue in internet sharing (ethernet) to Android device in Mavericks

Tags: ethernet, android, osx-mavericks, tethering

I have installed HoRNDIS driver on my Mavericks and my phone is displayed on network preferences (with green connected icon).

The issue is I cannot get access to the internet.

I shared the ethernet connection (from sharing preferences) and after that phone interface in network preference says not connected.